# cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, cuda

I get the following error when l run tensorflow in GPU.

```
2018-09-15 18:56:51.011724: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:158] Internal: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "evaluate_sample.py", line 160, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "evaluate_sample.py", line 123, in main
    with tf.Session() as sess:
  File "/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1494, in __init__
    super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 626, in __init__
    self._session = tf_session.TF_NewSession(self._graph._c_graph, opts)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to create session.
```

**Where do  the following errors come from  ?**

```
E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:158] Internal: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
```

**and**
**tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to create session**.

Such tha my version of :

tensorflow is : 1.10

```
cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
```

NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  390.77  Tue Jul 10 18:28:52 PDT 2018

GCC version:  gcc version 7.3.0 (Debian 7.3.0-28)

```
nvcc --version
```

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver

Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation

Built on Sun_Sep__4_22:14:01_CDT_2016

Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.44

Comment: your driver is incorrectly installed.  debian is not a supported OS for CUDA, and if you installed the driver using debian tools, that may be the problem

Answer (score 8):

Updating nvidia driver solved this issue.

You can check your cuda toolkit compatiblity [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html#binary-compatibility__table-toolkit-driver). Then update your nvidia driver by downloading it from [here](https://www.nvidia.in/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-in).

Answer (score 5):

In the case I just solved, it was updating the GPU driver to the latest and installing the cuda toolkit. Your error is telling you your CUDA driver version is too old.  I believe the nvcc version we were seeing was 7.5, and you have 7.3.

I think all you will have to do is: `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit` then reboot.

Below are the steps I took for the problem where the `libcuda.so.1` file could not be found.

First, the ppa was added and a newer GPU driver installed:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-390
```

After adding the ppa, it showed options for driver versions, and 390 was the latest 'stable' version that was shown.

Then install the cuda toolkit:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Then reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

It updated the drivers to a newer version than the 390 originally installed in the first step (it was 410; this was a p2.xlarge instance on AWS).

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. BTW I followed the above, also on a p2.xlarge instance, but I didn't need to reboot.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this error is the mismatch of your installed Cuda Toolkit version and the version of the python package cudatoolkit, which is usually installed as dependency of tensorflow-gpu.

In order to fix this you have to first match your tensorflow version with your installed Cuda Toolkit version like shown [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations)

Then you have to check the version of your cudatoolkit package. This have to match major and minor version, so e.g. if you have Cuda Toolkit 9.0 installed and cudatoolkit9_1 is installed you need to downgrade to cudatoolkit9 via your python.

Answer (score 1):

Just update your nvidia drivers and it will solve the issue

Comment: Provide the steps to update the driver along with the specific driver version if possible

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. Solved updating nvidia driver, because a I was using tensorflow 2.1 and it requires updated driver. Soo, I was using 390 and updated to 435, through Ubuntu's software manager.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Tensorflow 2.6.0 Solved my issue.

```sh
pip install --upgrade TensorFlow
```

Answer (score -2):

For Ubuntu 18.04 and Tensorflow 1.13.1

First make sure system is up to data:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo reboot now
```

Install later drivers:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

Open Software & Updates and select the Additional Drivers tab:

> Select the nvidia-driver-396 and click Apply Changes

Now reboot:

```
sudo reboot now
```

To verify which that NVIDIA driver 396 active:

```
nvidia-smi
```