# Trying to install tensorflow-gpu but got this error: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm relatively new working with Tensorflow and Keras, and I want to switch the process for my ANN with GPU. I tried some tutorials on YouTube, and it didn't work for me. So, I tried the simplest one that I found, and I attach the link below.

[Video tutorial on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UCn7EJYdA4)

I also changed some of the installed packages in the Anaconda environment because some guides told me that it could be some conflicting versions of cuDNN and CUDA. Here are some installed packages in the environment.

```
cudatoolkit               10.0.130                      0
cudnn                     7.6.5                cuda10.0_0
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_0
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1
tensorflow                1.14.0          gpu_py36h305fd99_0
tensorflow-base           1.14.0          gpu_py36h55fc52a_0
tensorflow-estimator      1.14.0                     py_0
tensorflow-gpu            1.14.0               h0d30ee6_0
```

When I run the command on IPython Console (from Spyder), this message alway appears after I run this command.

```
In [2]: from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
        print(device_lib.list_local_devices())

InternalError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
```

Comment: What do/don't you understand from that error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52346957/cudagetdevice-failed-status-cuda-driver-version-is-insufficient-for-cuda-run)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you updated your GPU driver? See [this table](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html#binary-compatibility__table-toolkit-driver) for the minimum version.

The easier way to run TensorFlow on your GPU is to use the container from NGC: https://ngc.nvidia.com/catalog/containers/nvidia:tensorflow